# Automate the Boring Stuff CH 10 - filling in the gaps

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, file-system

This exercise comes [from Automate the Boring Stuff CH 10 - second edition](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter10#calibre_link-348). The exercise is called "filling in the gaps," and the instructions are as follows:

> Write a program that finds all files with a given prefix, such as spam001.txt, spam002.txt, and so on, in a single folder and locates any gaps in the numbering (such as if there is a spam001.txt and spam003.txt but no spam002.txt). Have the program rename all the later files to close this gap.

I wrote two versions of this exercise. My first version was shorter than the second version, but the problem was that all the logic was contained in a single function. So I rewrote the code to separate it into multiple functions, and the result is posted here below. I have two major concerns with the logic of this program:

1. I believe that my logic is closer to a functional programming style, but I would like to better understand how I could approach this code from an object-oriented style
2. I am not sure that how I chose to organize the data is the best approach. This is something that I learned from this forum the last time I posted here, and since I am somewhat of a beginner, I'm attempting to develop a better understanding of data structures and how to organize data properly.

```py
#! python3
# fill_gaps.py -- search a single folder, find gaps in numbered files (ex. spam001.txt, spam003.txt)
# and rename later files to fill in the gaps.

import re, os, shutil
from pathlib import Path


def return_match_object(prefix: str) -> re.Match:
    # Remove numbers from prefix using a regex, then separate letters and numbers into groups
    return re.compile("(\D*)(\d*)").search(prefix)


def check_user_input(folder: str, regex_mo: re.Match) -> str | bool:
    if regex_mo is None:
        return "Invalid prefix. Prefix contains no letters or numbers."
    elif os.path.isdir(folder) == False:
        return "Invalid folder. Argument must be a valid folder path."
    else:
        return False


def create_file_list(regex_mo: re.Match) -> list:
    # Search folder for letters and add matches to a list
    letters = regex_mo.group(1)
    file_list = [i for i in os.listdir(".") if letters in i]
    return file_list


def create_number_list(file_list: list, regex_mo: re.Match) -> list:
    # search match_list for numbers and add them to a list
    number_list = []
    for file_name in file_list:
        mo = return_match_object(file_name)
        number_list.append(int(mo.group(2)))
    return number_list


def fill_gaps(
    file_list: list,
    number_list: list,
    folder: str,
    number_prefix_length: int,
    letters: str,
) -> list:
    # Rename later files to fill in gaps
    return_list = []
    for index, number in enumerate(number_list, 1):
        if index not in number_list:
            zeroes_to_add = "0" * (number_prefix_length - len(str(index)))
            suffix = Path(folder + "\\" + file_list[0]).suffix
            shutil.move(
                folder + "\\" + file_list[-1],
                folder + "\\" + letters + zeroes_to_add + str(index) + suffix,
            )
            return_list.append(
                "renamed "
                + file_list[-1]
                + " to "
                + letters
                + zeroes_to_add
                + str(index)
                + suffix
            )

    return return_list


def main() -> None:
    while True:
        folder = input("Please enter a folder to search for files\n")
        prefix = input("Please enter a prefix to search for, such as spam000\n")
        match_object = return_match_object(prefix)
        letters = match_object.group(1)
        number_prefix_length = len(match_object.group(2))
        # check for valid user input
        if type(check_user_input(folder, match_object)) == str:
            continue
        else:
            # main program execution
            os.chdir(folder)
            file_list = create_file_list(match_object)
            number_list = create_number_list(file_list, match_object)
            print(
                fill_gaps(file_list, number_list, folder, number_prefix_length, letters)
            )
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This is procedural programming, not functional programming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I believe that my logic is closer to a functional programming style

It isn't, and new developers often confuse this with procedural programming; yours is the latter.

Otherwise:

- Avoid `os` and `shutil` when `Path` has the same functionality with more convenient representation
- This application does not need regular expressions. Globs are more rudimentary, but fit the job. [Internally they use regular expressions anyway](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/pathlib.py#L192), but it's still probably a good idea to use the more constrained interface.
- I don't think that you should exclude prefixes that have no numbers. And I think that your definition of prefix is a little odd. The word "spam" alone should be your prefix.
- `check_user_input` should not return string-or-bool; it should throw-or-not.
- `create_file_list` would be well-represented by a generator function.
- You can replace `listdir` with `glob`.
- Consider separating your gap identification code from your renaming code.

### Example

This example code addresses the above and demonstrates an object-oriented renaming class.

```py
from pathlib import Path
from string import digits
from typing import Iterator, Iterable


class RenamingDir:
    SUFFIX_PAT = f'[{digits}]'*3 + '.txt'

    def __init__(self, directory: Path, prefix: str) -> None:
        self.directory = directory
        self.prefix = prefix

    def old_numbers(self) -> Iterator[int]:
        for file in self.directory.glob(self.prefix + self.SUFFIX_PAT):
            number = file.stem.removeprefix(self.prefix)
            yield int(number)

    def format_names(self, numbers: Iterable[int]) -> Iterator[Path]:
        for i in numbers:
            yield self.directory / f'{self.prefix}{i:03d}.txt'

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterable[tuple[
        Path,  # original path
        Path,  # new path
    ]]:
        numbers = sorted(self.old_numbers())
        for start, number in enumerate(numbers, start=1):
            if start != number:
                return zip(
                    self.format_names(numbers[start-1:]),
                    self.format_names(range(start, 1 + len(numbers)))
                )
        return ()

    def rename(self) -> None:
        for old, new in self:
            old.rename(new)


def main() -> None:
    while True:
        directory = Path(input("Please enter a directory to search for files: "))
        if directory.is_dir():
            break

    prefix = input("Please enter a prefix to search for, such as spam: ")
    RenamingDir(directory, prefix).rename()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hi, and thank you for taking the time to respond. I have a couple of follow up questions for you. 1. In your code example, am I to understand that your decision to use a class is the primary thing that makes it an example of OOP? 2. when you say that `check_user_input` should "throw-or-not," do you mean that such a function should be built for error handling?

Comment: 1. Basically, yes. It's easy to keep this as procedural-only, but you were curious about what OOP looks like, and this is one example.

Comment: 2. You can indeed build an error-handling function if you want. Inner validation functions should not print, and may return `True`/`False` but exceptions are generally a better idea.

Comment: Can you help me understand the purpose of the function `rename()`. It looks like it iterates through key/value pairs with the line `for old, new in self:`. If the latter is true, is the line `old.rename(new)` meant to rename the keys `old` with the values `new`? I am struggling to understand what is happening with this function, what data it takes in, and what its execution is.

Comment: The class itself is iterable via `__iter__`. When you say `for .. in self`, it calls `__iter__` which yields an iterable of pairs (old, new). Both elements are `Path`. `Path.rename` renames the given path to the new path.

Comment: So in this example `for old, new in self:` is not a typical for loop? Instead of `old` and `new` acting as iterators they retrieve the return statement from `__iter__`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136152/discussion-between-reinderien-and-ramza).